# What is a difference between self.view and self.view .superview of a rootViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a view controller which is assigned as a rootViewController like below :

```
self.viewCntrl = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewCntrl;
```

And in the same view controller i have a button and i am performing transition animation on button click like this:

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view.superview cache:YES];
```

but it not works when i write like this:

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
```

As here self is a ViewController's object, the ViewController which is nothing but **assigned to self.window.rootViewController**. So why it takes self.view.superview instead of self.view to animate?

Comment: what are you animating? what comes after `[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp...`?

Comment: i am animating the view which is my rootViewController's view. The code after [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp... is --- [UIView commitAnimations];
[self presentModalViewController:tabBarCntrl animated:NO];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the kind of animation you are trying to execute, possibly the answer is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationTransition%3aforView%3acache%3a):

> If you want to change the appearance of a view during a transition—for example, flip from one view to another—then use a container view, an instance of UIView, as follows:
>
> 1. Begin an animation block.
> 2. Set the transition on the container view.
> 3. Remove the subview from the container view.
> 4. Add the new subview to the container view.
> 5. Commit the animation block.

Comment: i am not adding any subviews, rather i am presenting another view controller. I want first viewcontroller's view animated before second appears!

Comment: well, you know, your `self.view` is a subview to `self.view.superview`. This is just a matter of how you look at things. Indeed, what you are doing is animating a subview of your current view's superview; so I think that the quote above is what explain why it works one way and not the other. In fact, it even says it explicitly: "for example, flip from one view to another". You are "curling up" from one view to another...

Comment: by the way, do you know that when presenting a modal view controller, you can specify the presented controller `modalTransitionStyle` property to get the same effect? `tabBarCntrl.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl`...

Comment: ahh thnks sergio. now i got it :]